# Why Force is called a vector quantity?

Tags: vectors, definition, physics

We have quantities which just adds up simply irrespective of any order and we call them scalars.

Then we have quantities which adds up algebraically according to their relative directions and we call them vectors. Under special conditions they adds up according to scalars.

So, given that Force adds up according to its absolute direction that is we additionally have to consider the line of action here just as we additionally have to consider the (relative) direction of quantities in vectors, shouldn't it be something more than a vector and classified accordingly?
Also, what are the other such type of quantities?

---

PS- Should I write Torque instead of Force since most of the time we don't have to account for the line of action of Force. If this is the case then feel free to edit the question.

Comment: i don't understand what you mean. You always account for the direction of the force in mechanics. E.g., when applying Newton's 2nd Law, you want to find the resultant of forces acting on the body, which requires looking at the directions, not just the magnitudes?

Comment: @gt6989b If I push your right shoulder hard enough you will turn one way and if I push your left shoulder with a force of the same magnitude in the same direction (an equal vector) you will turn the other way. The two forces have different turning effects so they are different forces even though they have the same 'vector properties'.

Comment: So, to completely specify a force we have to give it's magnitude direction and **line of action**

Comment: You're technically correct. By convention, when we refer to "force", we're implicitly talking about the net force acting through the center of mass of the object. All classical motion can be decomposed into two parts: the linear force through the center of mass as well as a torque about the center of mass, so there is no real loss of generality to refer to force and torque both as vectors.

Comment: If no other force exerts on your body, then pushing on your right shoulder and then left shoulder does not generate a torque.

Comment: Sure. If you want to look at it that way, then the concept you want is probably a [vector field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_field). But it is an unnecessary complication in most cases (one notable exception being fluid mechanics). In your example, pushing the right and left shoulders with equal forces generates a net force on the center of mass, and zero net torque about the center of mass. That alone is enough to specify the dynamics of the body.

Comment: It would be nice to expand this question and first explain all terms: what is force? what is a definition of vector? how do we understand a quantity? And then find a connection between them.

Answer (score 1):

A single force can be represented by an arrow (a simple assumption)

[image]

An arrow is one-dimensional.

As by Google, a

Vector is:

> a quantity having direction as well as magnitude, especially as determining the position of one point in space relative to another.

Quantity is:

> the amount or number of a material or abstract thing not usually estimated by spatial measurement.

We know that the length of an arrow represents the power of a force, or in other words, the *quantity*. Also, we know that the direction of an arrow is it's, well direction, and the magnitude being the *quantity*. And, also, it is actually determining the position of a point in space relative to another! The comparison is, well an origin on a set of coordinates, longitude and latitude in real life, and there are also many more examples!

From this, we conclude that it is not necessary to classify as something else.

As for your last question, I don't understand what is meant by *such quantities*, so therefore, I cannot answer that (probably because of my poor comprehension...)

Answer (score 0):

In the experiment, the two pushes have the same force, but different torque. In that kind of analysis, the forces are free vectors, so is, equivalence classes of oriented segments: each vector is the class containing all segments with the same length, direction and sense. In the diagrams aren't the vectors drawn, but a representative of the relevant class. In the analysis of the pushes we write for the first:

$\vec\tau_1=\vec r\times\vec F$, measured respect to some point in the chest. The second is $\vec\tau_2=(-\vec r)\times\vec F$ same symbol because the force is the same.

So, you can push with the same force both shoulders and no torque because $\vec\tau_1+\vec\tau_2=\vec r\times\vec F+(-\vec r)\times\vec F=(\vec r-\vec r)\times\vec F=0$ (and $M\vec a=\vec F+\vec F=2\vec F$, too), So is, you need identify somehow the, apparently, different forces and it's done by means the concept of equivalence classes.

The two different pushes seem in fact different and we first think of the forces, but the theory says where is actually the difference and it's not in the forces.